# Why prototype of array is an array

Tags: prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Prototype of a function is a Function.
Prototype of an array is an Array.
Prototype of an object is an Object.

WHY?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Prototype of a function is a Function.**

function inherit from Prototype function
this what it look like = function(){}
the type is function

**Prototype of an array is an Array.**

Array inherit from Prototype Array
this what it look like = []
the type is Array
you can insert to that by push= [].push('why you ask basic question')
and you can call it by = array_name[0]

**Prototype of an object is an Object**

Object inherit from Prototype Object
this what it look like = {}
the type is Object
you can insert to that by = {}['question']='why you ask basic question'
and you can call it by = obj_name['question']

> do you know function,Object,Array? the prototype just constructure for
>   it so when the error say prototype function is error that mean your
>   function sistem not right, you not type it right or you not do it
>   right, some think must be crush on it repair it